# How to sort a list alphabetically and depending on length

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a list that I would like to sort alphanumerically. I currently have 
my list sorted like:

```
Column B    Column C    
LC-94774    102-A    
LC-94774    102-AA    
LC-94774    102-AF    
LC-94774    102-AG    
LC-94774    102-AP    
LC-94774    102-T    
LC-94774    104-M    
LC-94774    105-AA    
LC-94774    105-C    
LC-94774    105-L    
LC-94773    1    
LC-94773    2    
LC-94773    3    
LC-94773    2A
```

But I am trying to sort it towards:

```
Column B        Column C    
LC-94774    102-A    
LC-94774    102-T    
LC-94774    102-AA    
LC-94774    102-AF    
LC-94774    102-AG    
LC-94774    102-AP    
LC-94774    104-M    
LC-94774    105-C    
LC-94774    105-L    
LC-94774    105-AA    
LC-94773    1    
LC-94773    2    
LC-94773    2A    
LC-94773    3
```

Currently, I have the following written code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub telecomsorter()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim First As Long
Dim Last As Long
Dim r As Long

With Worksheets("TELECOM")

lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Range("B13:C" & lastRow).Select

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TELECOM").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TELECOM").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "B14:B" & lastRow & ""), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
        "BMC-*,CSR-*,MC-*,LC-*," & Chr(42) & "", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TELECOM").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "C14:C" & lastRow & ""), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal

  With ActiveSheet.Sort
      .SetRange Range("B14:C" & lastRow)
      .Header = xlNo
      .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
      .Apply
  End With

 Call SortSpecial("LC-*", xlDescending)
 Call SortSpecial("MC-*", xlAscending)
 Call SortSpecial("LC-*", xlAscending)
 Call SortSpecial("LC-*", xlDescending)
End With




End Sub

Public Function SortSpecial(ByVal StrVal As String, ByVal SortOrder As XlSortOrder)

  Dim First As Long
  Dim Last As Long

  First = Columns("B").Find(StrVal, , xlValues, , xlRows, xlNext, , , False).Row
  Last = Columns("B").Find(StrVal, , xlValues, , xlRows, xlPrevious, , , False).Row

  ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
  ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B" & First & ":B" & Last), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=SortOrder, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

  With ActiveSheet.Sort

  If SortOrder = xlAscending Then
    .SetRange Range("B" & First & ":C" & Last)
  Else
  Last = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  .SetRange Range("B" & First & ":C" & Last)
  End If

    .Header = xlNo
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .Apply

  End With

End Function
```

NEW EDIT:
No, Its just that I want to sort column B first, then for Column C, sort in kinda this:

LC-94774    102-A

LC-94774    102-B

LC-94774    102-AA

Notice how that it is NOT sorted like: (This is how is currently sorted)

LC-94774    102-A

LC-94774    102-AA

LC-94774    102-B

Notice how it sorts the A's on top first, then the B's next. I want it to go in alphabetical single letters first, then AA AB AC..etc (kinda like how MS excel in columns are set up)

NEW EDIT 04/09/2019:

```
Option Explicit
Sub sortAlphaNum()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Range
    Dim wsSort As Worksheet
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vToSort As Variant
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Const sPat As String = "(\d+)-?(\D*)" 'note that some do not have a hyphen
    Dim I As Long, V As Variant
    Dim LCstartrow As Integer
    Dim LCendrow As Integer
    Dim J As Long

'input data to variant array
Set ws = Worksheets("TELECOM")

'Finding the row in which the first LC-* Drawing starts

Dim xRow As Integer
Dim strSearch As String

strSearch = "LC-*" 'Find the first
' Assuming Total is in column C as your picture shows, but you can configure to search anywhere

xRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("$C1:C" & xRow).Select

J = Selection.Find(What:=strSearch, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select

With ws
    vSrc = .Range(ActiveCell, .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=2)
End With

'create array of ColB, and Col C split into Numeric, Alpha & len(alpha) for column c
'cannot split column 2 on the hyphen since not all requiring a split contain a hyphen.

ReDim vToSort(1 To UBound(vSrc, 1), 1 To 7)

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = False
    .ignorecase = False 'or could be true
    .Pattern = sPat
End With
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    Set MC = RE.Execute(vSrc(I, 2))
        vToSort(I, 1) = vSrc(I, 1)
            V = Split(vSrc(I, 1), "-")
        vToSort(I, 2) = V(0)
        vToSort(I, 3) = V(1)
    Set MC = RE.Execute(vSrc(I, 2))
        vToSort(I, 4) = vSrc(I, 2)
        vToSort(I, 5) = MC(0).submatches(0)
        vToSort(I, 6) = MC(0).submatches(1)
        vToSort(I, 7) = Len(vToSort(I, 6))
Next I

'write to hidden sheet for sorting
Set wsSort = Worksheets.Add
With wsSort
    '.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    Set r = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vToSort, 1), UBound(vToSort, 2))
    r.Value = vToSort
End With

'sort on the hidden sheet
wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=r.Columns(2) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:="BMC,CSR,MC,LC" _
        , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=r.Columns(3) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=r.Columns(5) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=r.Columns(7) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=r.Columns(6) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With wsSort.Sort
        .SetRange r
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

'create results array with the needed columns
Dim vRes1 As Variant, vRes2 As Variant

Set r = Union(r.Columns(1), r.Columns(4))

vRes1 = r.Areas(1)
vRes2 = r.Areas(2)
'write back to the original sheet
'but offset for now for trouble shooting

Set r = Worksheets("Telecom").Cells(1, 8).Resize(UBound(vRes1, 1), 2)
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
With r

    .Columns(1).Value = vRes1
    .Columns(2).Value = vRes2
    .EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

'delete the hidden sheet
    .DisplayAlerts = False
        'wsSort.Delete
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: hi. i didnt analise the code, but wheres the problem ? the  result is not what u expect  or theres some kind of error ?

Comment: Yeah, I can't get my code to sort alphanumerically, like the order shown above @LuisCurado

Comment: What, exactly, are your sorting rules for column C.

Comment: WHY would you want a convoluted sorting?? I could only think that it is to match some other list that has such a convolution.   With the only reason is to MATCH.  Ergo, why not match on a simpler and more normal sorting.  And as such, sort BOTH sets in a normal sort.  Why not??

Comment: This is some strange sorting. I would create three new columns. First would be `=Left(C1, Find("-", C1)-1)` for the numeric portion before the hyphen. Next would be `=Len(Right(C1, Len(C1)-Find("-", C1)))` to get the length of the portion after the hyphen. And then the last column would be `=Right(C1, Len(C1)-Find("-", C1))` to get the bit after the hyphen. Then sort everything by those three columns in order.

Comment: No, Its just that I want to sort column B first, then for Column C, sort in kinda this: LC-94774    102-A    
LC-94774    102-AA

Comment: *kinda this …* does not provide a sorting rule that can be translated to a computer algorithm.  If that is all you have, then there is no need to sort.  If you have more data, as you do in your example, you need to provide more specific rules.

Comment: No, Its just that I want to sort column B first, then for Column C, sort in kinda this: LC-94774    102-A    
LC-94774    102-B
LC-94774    102-AA                                            
                                                                                                             
Notice how that it is NOT sorted like:                                                                                                                                                                                          LC-94774    102-A    
LC-94774    102-B    
LC-94774    102-AA

Comment: I have also posted this comment in the New edit portion of my question, so you could see the sorting pattern a little better.

Comment: @RawrRawr7 so, the column B sort should be straightforward.  it *looks* like you want to first loop through your data and add related items to an array/dictionary/collection, then sort those items independent of each other.  something like `if right(left(val,4),1) = "-" then` and if `true` add to arr 1, if `false` add to arr 2.  when done transpose dict 1 data, sort it, then after last row transpose dict 2 data and sort it

Comment: @Cyril I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: @RawrRawr7 from all of the comments and understanding the little bit of data provided in your post, you are essentially sorting 2+ separate groups of data using standard Excel sorting.  The first set is all of your ###-* data, the second is #A, etc.  You want to group those separate datasets together, then sort each individually.  I recommended pulling them each to their own dictionary or array as those can be transposed pretty quickly, followed by standard excel sort after `application.transpose`.  You will need to come up with your own logic to support the grouping of datasets.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to sort

- Column B : Ascending for the first part of string in a custom order
- Column B : Descending for the second part (numeric) of the string
- Column C : Ascending for the numeric portion
- Column C : Ascending for the length of the alpha portion
- Column C : Ascending for the alpha portion of the string

For Column B, the two parts can be split on the hyphen
For Column C, since there isn't always a hyphen, I used Regular Expressions to split the alpha and numeric portions, but other methods can be used.

The method used is to split the data into multiple columns, and sort on each as required.  This sorting is done on a throw-away worksheet, and then the results copied back to the original sheet.

For the code, I have offset the results from the original for debugging purposes, since there may be configurations for which you have not provided information.  But it does produce the desired results on your test data.

```
Option Explicit
Sub sortAlphaNum()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Range
    Dim wsSort As Worksheet
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vToSort As Variant
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Const sPat As String = "(\d+)-?(\D*)" 'note that some do not have a hyphen
    Dim I As Long, V As Variant

'input data to variant array
Set ws = Worksheets("Telecom")
With ws
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=2)
End With

'create array of ColB, and Col C split into Numeric, Alpha & len(alpha) for column c
'cannot split column 2 on the hyphen since not all requiring a split contain a hyphen.

ReDim vToSort(1 To UBound(vSrc, 1), 1 To 7)

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = False
    .ignorecase = False 'or could be true
    .Pattern = sPat
End With
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    Set MC = RE.Execute(vSrc(I, 2))
        vToSort(I, 1) = vSrc(I, 1)
            V = Split(vSrc(I, 1), "-")
        vToSort(I, 2) = V(0)
        vToSort(I, 3) = V(1)
    Set MC = RE.Execute(vSrc(I, 2))
        vToSort(I, 4) = vSrc(I, 2)
        vToSort(I, 5) = MC(0).submatches(0)
        vToSort(I, 6) = MC(0).submatches(1)
        vToSort(I, 7) = Len(vToSort(I, 6))
Next I

'write to hidden sheet for sorting
Set wsSort = Worksheets.Add
With wsSort
    .Visible = xlSheetHidden
    Set r = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vToSort, 1), UBound(vToSort, 2))
    r.Value = vToSort
End With

'sort on the hidden sheet
wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=r.Columns(2) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:="BMC,CSR,MC,LC" _
        , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=r.Columns(3) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=r.Columns(5) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=r.Columns(7) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=r.Columns(6) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With wsSort.Sort
        .SetRange r
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

'create results array with the needed columns
Dim vRes1 As Variant, vRes2 As Variant
Set r = Union(r.Columns(1), r.Columns(4))

vRes1 = r.Areas(1)
vRes2 = r.Areas(2)

'write back to the original sheet
'but offset for now for trouble shooting
Set r = Worksheets("Telecom").Cells(1, 5).Resize(UBound(vRes1, 1), 2)
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
With r
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Columns(1).Value = vRes1
    .Columns(2).Value = vRes2
    .EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

'delete the hidden sheet
    .DisplayAlerts = False
        wsSort.Delete
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ron! I manipulated the program a little bit. However, I would like for this just to sort my LC-XXXXX values only. I was wondering would it be possible to somewhat extract these new LC values to and paste them over the original ones?

Comment: "Your new program" contains a substantial portion of the **code I provided**, and does nothing to indicate the problem with this code.  And I am offended that you just plagiarized the idea and claim it as *your new program*. If all you want is for *LC- values to come after my MC-ones*, then just sort from *z to a*.  But that is not what you show in your examples.  So far as pasting them where you want, all you need to do is change the location where they are pasted.  Since you've appropriated my code as your own, I assume you can see how that is done.